# How to get the DATABASE_URL from a rails project on cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, cloud9-ide

I have a rails project running on cloud9, and I want to dup it to my local machine so I can continue working on it locally.

The problem however is that I have data on cloud9 database already which I'll like to continue utilizing, either while on cloud9 or on my local machine.

> I know that including `DATABASE_URL` in my env vars for the project will ensure that the app connects to the specified database [as stated here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database).

To this end, my question is this:

**How can I get the `database url` being used on the cloud9 instance, so I can just use it directly from my env vars on my local machine? or... is this not possible?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that database on cloud9 is only available from inside the cloud. To replicate the setup on a local machine you would have to set up your own database

To dump the database on cloud9 you can use [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) in the cloud9 terminal, and then [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) on your local machine (or vice versa to move the dump from your local machine to cloud9)

Comment: no, you will have to somehow sync your local database and the cloud one

Comment: hmm... okay... do you have any suggestion for how i may be able to go about that somehow?

Comment: I'm guessing this won't provide a workaround for you but for the sake of information: On Cloud9, you can make processes and endpoints available publicly on port 8080, 8081, and 8082 but these are only accessible via https. For more info see [Multiple Ports](https://docs.c9.io/docs/multiple-ports). Hopefully that at least makes it a little clearer.